# KendoUI Embedded External Links

Tags: iframe, mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am using Telerik's KendoUI framework for an HTML5/JS mobile app. When I have views I want to link to inside my app, I do a standard link such as `<a href="path/to/view.html">Link</a>` which is of course as basic as it gets. The question I have is whether there is a way to make that path an external link, but have the page load inside the content area of the app (such as in an iFrame)? I'm not finding any examples of that online and when I make the link external, my whole app disappears if you click it. The end goal is keeping the link's site content (already mobile friendly) in between the header/footer of my app so they can still navigate it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through Telerik support, this wasn't natively possible with their framework. I ended up doing a Kendo view and utilized the `data-init` option to dynamically build an `<iframe />` via jQuery and put the link in there so it loaded appropriately. Some might say that's a security concern, however in our case the link is something we put in for them so it's something that will always be trusted.